# AngularJS Resolve a route based on a service promise

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-ng-route

I am using ngRoute and and trying to get my routes to resolve based on the result of a function in a service I have defined

My service is as follows:

```
app.factory('AuthService', function ($q,$location,$http) {
var isLoggedIn = false;

    return {
        hasLoginSession: function(){
            var defer = $q.defer();
            if(isLoggedIn) {
                //User has a valid session from a previous GetSession.json request
                defer.resolve(isLoggedIn);
            } else {


                return $http.get('/session/GetSession.json').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    isLoggedIn = data.success;
                    if(isLoggedIn) {
                        defer.resolve(isLoggedIn);
                    }
                    else {
                        defer.reject("EX_LOGIN_SESSION_IS_UNKNOWN");
                    }
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    isLoggedIn=false;
                    defer.reject("EX_LOGIN_SESSION_IS_UNKNOWN");
                });

            }
            return defer.promise;

        }
    };

});
```

So as you can see I just have a simple session check function which sets a property based on the result of a http request.

I then have the routing setup like so, with a resolve just on the route path for testing at the moment:

```
var app = angular.module('pinpointersApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(
  function($routeProvider,$httpProvider) {
      //$httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);

     $routeProvider.
     when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
      }).
      when('/map', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/map.html',
        controller: 'MapController'
      }).
      when('/locations', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/locations.html',
        controller: 'LocationsController'
       }).
     when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/locations.html',
        controller: 'LocationsController',
        resolve: {
            checkSession: function ($q,AuthService) {
                //var defer = $q.defer();
                //defer.reject("EX_LOGIN_SESSION_IS_UNKNOWN");
                //return defer.promise;
                return AuthService.hasLoginSession();

            }

        }


    });

});

app.run(['$rootScope', 'AuthService', function ($rootScope, AuthService) {
   $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function (event, current, previous, error) {
       console.log(error);
       //Perform other stuff here, e.g. redirect to login view
   });

}]);
```

The server side request is being made, and I am seeing a pause in the view loading until the response is received. In my test I am returning a fail case and so reject the state of the promise in order to cause the $routeChangeError to be fired, but it never does and my view continues to load.

If I use the commented out lines of test code in my resolve block instead of my service routine call, so

```
resolve: {
            checkSession: function ($q,AuthService) {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                defer.reject("EX_LOGIN_SESSION_IS_UNKNOWN");
                return defer.promise;
                //return AuthService.hasLoginSession();

            }

        }
```

then the routeChangeError event is fired, so what am I missing in order to just use the result of my service routine call?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out what I did wrong, in my service I had one too many return statements, I just needed to remove the return keyword before my opening $http request and now it works as required.